# How can I exclude rows in a Copy Data Activity in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have built an Pipeline with one Copy Data activity which copies data from an `Azure Data Lake` and output it to an `Azure Blob Storage`.

In the output, I can see that some of my rows do not have data and I would like to exclude them from the copy. In the following example, the 2nd row does not have useful data:

```
{"TenantId":"qa","Timestamp":"2019-03-06T10:53:51.634Z","PrincipalId":2,"ControlId":"729c3b6e-0442-4884-936c-c36c9b466e9d","ZoneInternalId":0,"IsAuthorized":true,"PrincipalName":"John","StreetName":"Rue 1","ExemptionId":8}
{"TenantId":"qa","Timestamp":"2019-03-06T10:59:09.74Z","PrincipalId":null,"ControlId":null,"ZoneInternalId":null,"IsAuthorized":null,"PrincipalName":null,"StreetName":null,"ExemptionId":null}
```

**Question**

In the Copy Data activity, how can I put a rule to exclude rows that miss certain values?

Here is the code of my pipeline :

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Copy from Data Lake to Blob",
                "type": "Copy",
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [
                    {
                        "name": "Source",
                        "value": "tenantdata/events/"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Destination",
                        "value": "controls/"
                    }
                ],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "AzureDataLakeStoreSource",
                        "recursive": true
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "BlobSink",
                        "copyBehavior": "MergeFiles"
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "columnMappings": {
                            "Body.TenantId": "TenantId",
                            "Timestamp": "Timestamp",
                            "Body.PrincipalId": "PrincipalId",
                            "Body.ControlId": "ControlId",
                            "Body.ZoneId": "ZoneInternalId",
                            "Body.IsAuthorized": "IsAuthorized",
                            "Body.PrincipalName": "PrincipalName",
                            "Body.StreetName": "StreetName",
                            "Body.Exemption.Kind": "ExemptionId"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "qadl",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "datalakestaging",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very good question (+1 for that), I had the same question months back and I was surprised that I could not find anything within the Copy Activity to handle this (I even tried with the fault tolerance feature but no luck).

And given that I had other transformations going on in my pipelines with [U-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/), I ended up using it to accomplish this. So, instead of a Copy Activity I have a [U-SQL Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-data-lake-analytics) in ADF using the [IS NOT NULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/operators/comparison/is-null) operator, it depends on your data but you can play with that, maybe your string contains the "NULL" or empty strings "", this is how it looks :

```
DECLARE @file_set_path string = "adl://myadl.azuredatalake.net/Samples/Data/{date_utc:yyyy}{date_utc:MM}{date_utc:dd}T{date_utc:HH}{date_utc:mm}{date_utc:ss}Z.txt";

@data =
    EXTRACT 
            [id] string,
            date_utc DateTime
    FROM @file_set_path
    USING Extractors.Text(delimiter: '\u0001', skipFirstNRows : 1, quoting:false);

@result =
    SELECT 

            [id] ,
            date_utc.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss") AS SourceExtractDateUTC
    FROM @data
    WHERE id IS NOT NULL -- you can also use WHERE id <> "" or <> "NULL";

OUTPUT @result TO "wasb://samples@mywasb/Samples/Data/searchlog.tsv" USING Outputters.Text(delimiter: '\u0001', outputHeader:true);
```

Notes: ADLS and Blob storage are supported [INPUT/OUTPUT files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/Concepts/files/input-files#registerWABS)

Let me know if that helps or if the example above does not work for your data. 
Hopefully somebody will post an answer using Copy Activity and that'd be awesome but this is one possibility so far.

Comment: I will try this and let you know as soon as possible :)

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I wonder if I am doing the right thing. The Copy Data is [meant]( to copy files as-is between two file-based data stores, in which case the data is copied efficiently without any serialization/deserialization) to copy the data as-is, efficiently without any serialization/deserialization. That might explain why there are no options for the Copy Data activity...

Comment: @Kzrystof agreed, removing null values might be considered a transformation, and you can either do that with Python (Databricks) or U-SQL, or even with SQL if you store this into a SQL table. However there is already a fault tolerance under the Copy Activity's Settings tab, that might be a good place to do this, if you can skip "incompatible" rows already, I don't see why not skipping rows with specific columns being NULL =) anyway my 2 cents.

Comment: USQL in ADF is going to retire on February 28 , 2024. any other options to exclude first and last row in copy activity & also we have requirement to add new column in destination with default value Date value passed in expression. How to achieve this requirement in ADF