# Using ADF REST connector to read and transform FHIR data

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, hl7-fhir

I am trying to use Azure Data Factory to read data from a FHIR server and transform the results into newline delimited JSON (ndjson) files in Azure Blob storage. Specifically, if you query a FHIR server, you might get something like:

```
{
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    "id": "som-id",
    "type": "searchset",
    "link": [
        {
            "relation": "next",
            "url": "https://fhirserver/?ct=token"
        },
        {
            "relation": "self",
            "url": "https://fhirserver/"
        }
    ],
    "entry": [
        {
            "fullUrl": "https://fhirserver/Organization/1234",
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Organization",
                "id": "1234",
                // More fields
        },
        {
            "fullUrl": "https://fhirserver/Organization/456",
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Organization",
                "id": "456",
                // More fields
        },

        // More resources
    ]
}
```

Basically a bundle of resources. I would like to transform that into a newline delimited (aka ndjson) file where each line is just the json for a resource:

```
{"resourceType": "Organization", "id": "1234", // More fields }
{"resourceType": "Organization", "id": "456", // More fields }
// More lines with resources
```

I am able to get the REST connector set up and it can query the FHIR server (including pagination), but no matter what I try I cannot seem to generate the ouput I want. I set up an Azure Blob storage dataset:

```
{
    "name": "AzureBlob1",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureBlobStorage1",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "type": "AzureBlob",
        "typeProperties": {
            "format": {
                "type": "JsonFormat",
                "filePattern": "setOfObjects"
            },
            "fileName": "myout.json",
            "folderPath": "outfhirfromadf"
        }
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}
```

And configure a copy activity:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Copy Data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "RestSource",
                        "httpRequestTimeout": "00:01:40",
                        "requestInterval": "00.00:00:00.010"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "BlobSink"
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "schemaMapping": {
                            "resource": "resource"
                        },
                        "collectionReference": "$.entry"
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "FHIRSource",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "AzureBlob1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

But at the end (in spite of configuring the schema mapping), it the end result in the blob is always just the original bundle returned from the server. If I configure the output blob as being a comma delimited text, I can extract fields and create a flattened tabular view, but that is not really what I want.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: My experience so far with Azure Data Factory's Copy Activity is that it only copy data from place to another and everytime I needed some sort of transformation, I got hurt :)  Would that be acceptable for you to consider Databricks and use some python/scala scripting to do the transformation you need?

Comment: @Kzrystof, thanks for your comment. That would be one possible option. I guess I was trying to see how far I could get with ADF on this path. So yes, definitely an option, but I would also like to know if this is (or will be) possible with ADF.

Comment: Oh I understand you mean :) I actually [asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55050376/how-can-i-exclude-rows-in-a-copy-data-activity-in-azure-data-factory) few weeks ago about how a Copy Activity could exclude rows that wouldn't fit a certain criteria...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I sort of found a solution. If I do the original step of converting where the bundles are simply dumped in the JSON file and then do a nother conversion from the JSON file to what I pretend to be a text file into another blob, I can get the njson file created.

Basically, define another blob dataset:

```
{
    "name": "AzureBlob2",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureBlobStorage1",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "type": "AzureBlob",
        "structure": [
            {
                "name": "Prop_0",
                "type": "String"
            }
        ],
        "typeProperties": {
            "format": {
                "type": "TextFormat",
                "columnDelimiter": ",",
                "rowDelimiter": "",
                "quoteChar": "",
                "nullValue": "\\N",
                "encodingName": null,
                "treatEmptyAsNull": true,
                "skipLineCount": 0,
                "firstRowAsHeader": false
            },
            "fileName": "myout.json",
            "folderPath": "adfjsonout2"
        }
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}
```

Note that this one `TextFormat` and also note that the `quoteChar` is blank. If I then add another Copy Activity:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Copy Data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "RestSource",
                        "httpRequestTimeout": "00:01:40",
                        "requestInterval": "00.00:00:00.010"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "BlobSink"
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "schemaMapping": {
                            "['resource']": "resource"
                        },
                        "collectionReference": "$.entry"
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "FHIRSource",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "AzureBlob1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Copy Data2",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Copy Data1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "BlobSource",
                        "recursive": true
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "BlobSink"
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "columnMappings": {
                            "resource": "Prop_0"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "AzureBlob1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "AzureBlob2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

Then it all works out. It is not ideal in that I now have two copies of the data in blobs, but one can easily be deleted, I suppose.

I would still love to hear about it if somebody has a one-step solution.

Answer (score 0):

As briefly discussed in the comment, the `Copy Activity` does not provide much functionality aside from mapping data. As stated in the documentation, the [Copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) does the following operations:

> 1. Reads data from a source data store.
> 2. Performs serialization/deserialization, compression/decompression, column mapping, etc. It does these operations based on the
>      configurations of the input dataset, output dataset, and Copy
>      Activity.
> 3. Writes data to the sink/destination data store.

It does not look like that the `Copy Activity` does anything else aside from efficiently copying stuff around.

What I found out to be working was to use Databrick.

Here are the steps:

1. Add a Databricks account to your subscription;
2. Go to the Databricks page by clicking the authoring button;
3. Create a notebook;
4. Write the script (Scala, Python or [.Net was recently announced](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/data/spark)).

The script would the following:

1. Read the data from the Blob storage;
2. Filter out & transform the data as needed;
3. Write the data back to a Blob storage;

You can test your script from there and, once ready, you can go back to your pipeline and create a [Notebook activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-notebook) that will point to your notebook containing the script.

I struggled coding in Scala but it was worth it :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this post in the future you can just can use the $export api call to accomplish this. Note that you have to have a storage account linked to your Fhir server.

https://build.fhir.org/ig/HL7/bulk-data/export.html#endpoint---system-level-export